# Major improvements from Groovy 1.8 to 2.0 (Groovy 1.8 vs 2.0)

Tags: groovy

Could i know what are the major additions/improvements in terms of code level in Groovy 2.0 compare to Groovy 1.8.

Sorry for disturb, but i browse in net, every where i found, very high level explanation like supports that one this one like this.

Please tell me if you know any thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- InfoQ has very good and detailed article about improvements in Groovy 2.0: http://www.infoq.com/articles/new-groovy-20
- official announce http://glaforge.appspot.com/article/groovy-2-0-released

Comment: WOW, it really wonderful and very very detailed... thanks one more time my dear friend **Igor Artamonov**.

Answer (score -1):

One major addition in Groovy 2.0 over 1.8 is allowing statically-typed compilation using an annotation:

```
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic

@CompileStatic int triple(int n){
  n * 3
}

triple(5)
```

instead of the dynamically-compiled code:

```
def triple(int n){
  n * 3
}

triple(5)
```

The upside of the static compilation mode is faster execution times. The downside is it's totally new software released only 1 year ago, hasn't been thoroughly tested, and isn't used by Groovy's main users, i.e. Grails and Gradle. AFAIK, Grails 2.2 and Gradle 1.4 don't use any of the static compilation available in Groovy 2.0.

In summary, best wait until one or both of those products are confident enough of Groovy static compilation to use it before using it for your own software.